# jQuery val() not updating input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have input field:

```
<input class="form-control" id="Page" min="1" name="Page" type="number" value="1">
```

and with jQuery I'm trying to change value after button press. 
Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Right").on("click", function () {
        var page = $("#Page").val();
        page = page++;
        $("#Page").val(page);
})
```

I can read value. 
increment it. 
But when I'm trying to save it to he input field value it's keeps old value.

I also tried parsing it to int like this:

```
 var value= parseInt(page);
 value = value++;
 $("#Page").val(value);
```

And this also gave no effect.

Can you suggest something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use `page++;`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Right").on("click", function () {
        var page = parseInt($("#Page").val());
        page++;
        $("#Page").val(page);
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/jrCj9/1/)

`value++` is known as postfix , add 1 to a returns the old value.Hence while using `value = value++;` , the value of `value` will be always `1`

Comment: Thanks. What a shameful mistake :(

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that value = value++ won't sum, instead use just value++.

```
var value = parseInt(page);
value++;
$("#Page").val(value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert the value as integer, then apply increment. Try with this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#Right").on("click", function () {
    var page = parseInt( $("#Page").val() );
    page++;
    $("#Page").val(page);
})
```

Comment: You can edit your answer `page=page++` is not working